# Redis Pub/sub:How to use redis hashes in redis pub-sub using php?

Tags: php, redis

I want to use redis-hashes in the redis pub/sub's subscriber part
but whlile using this the subscriber exits . look at code for more clear

**Publisher.php**

```
$redis = getRedis();
$redis->publish("foo", "Hii");
```

**Subscriber.php**

```
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', -1);
    $redis = getRedis();

    $redis->subscribe(array("foo"), 'f');

    print "\n";

    function f($redis, $chan, $msg) {
       echo $msg.'\n';

       $redis->hSet("h", "h-key", "h-value");
       $read_val = $redis->hGet("h","h-key");
       echo $read_val;

}
```

Now here 1st run Subscriber.php from command-line

and then Publisher.php
So as per publisher run subscriber print "Hi" and then it should have to print "h-value"
but subscriber exits with no error normally it should be stay in running state.
So what would be the reason of subscriber stopping?
I used redis-cli to check value of "h-key" under "h" using

```
>hget h h-key
```

in cmd but it shows "(nil)"

So can we use redis's any other model in subscriber?

Comment: Shouldn't there be some kind of loop in subscriber? Otherwise it just exits, because there's nothing to do.

Comment: after that also subscriber should be always UP right still we manually stop it @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Yeah, so do something about it. :)

Comment: actually I want to use redis's hset/hget in pub-sub but its not setting and getting values I checked it in redis-cli

Comment: It's because subscriber exits before you publish that event

Comment: no no its not like that subscriber showing me output "hi" which is published by channel "foo" but its not setting and getting values next echo doesn't show anything